# ¿Estoy poniendo mal el lock? ¿Dónde debería ir en este thread?

Tags: python, hilos

Estoy intentando resolver este problema pero no lo logro hacer.

```
import multiprocessing
import threading


contador = 0
**lock = threading.Lock()**

def funcion(lock):
    global contador
    **lock.acquire()**
    for i in range(1000000):
        contador += 1
    **lock.release()**

print("Inicio programa principal")
print("Valor Inicial: " + str(contador))

thread_1=threading.Thread(target=funcion, **args=(lock)**)
thread_2=threading.Thread(target=funcion, **args=(lock)**)
thread_3=threading.Thread(target=funcion, **args=(lock)**)

thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
thread_3.start()

thread_1.join()
thread_2.join()
thread_3.join()

print("Valor Final: " + str(contador))
```

Alguien sabe si estoy utilizando mal los locks? La idea es que devuelva un millón, ya que los tres hilos se tienen que ayudar a contar hasta ese número, pero cuentan hasta tres millones. Lo que tiene asteriscos es lo que yo escribí sobre el ejercicio de práctica original. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de `for i in range(1000000)` debería ser `while contador < 1000000`, si no cada hilo suma 1 millón y terminas con 3 millones.